# How to clear the selection of QListView when multiple items are selected?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlistview

I am working on a Qt App where I have a QListView. There are few items present in the list. My application requires items to be rearranged according to user's choice. Everything is working fine but I am facing a small issue.

When I do multiple selection using a mouse i.e. select items by dragging the mouse, it leaves the selection mark on the QlistView even after I do some rearranging operation. I am sure its got something to do with clearing the selection. I tried to use repaint() or clearFocus() but nothing seems to be working.

E.g When we select a group of folders we drag our mouse, which intern gives us rectangular box which covers all the items which come under it. That particular rectangle box stays inside my QListView. I do not want it after I have selected the items.

I have a mousemoveevent inside which I am doing it:

```
    void BinListView::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *event) {

        if (NULL == event) {
            return;
        } else {

            if (Qt::LeftButton & event->buttons ()) {
                int nDis = (event->pos () - m_posStart).manhattanLength ();

                if (nDis >= QApplication::startDragDistance ()) {
                    startDrag (m_posStart);
                }
            }

#ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG
            QListView::mouseMoveEvent (event);
            QListView::repaint();
            QListView::clearFocus();

#endif

        }
        repaint();
    }
```

If you notice QT_NO_DEBUG area, you will see my clearing focus and repainting but nothing is helping me. ANy solution to this problem?

P.S.: I am running it in a release mode.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
void QAbstractItemView::clearSelection() [slot]
```

to clear selection

Also, all views have a selection model you can access through:

```
QItemSelectionModel * QAbstractItemView::selectionModel() const
```

that allows doing a lot more things selecting

Look at [Handling selections in item views](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-in-item-views)

Another thing ...

```
#ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG
```

means release

```
#ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG
```

would be debug mode, and im sure, it will not compile the code you pasted

Comment: Clear selection will not let me select the items. My concern is when I am dragging the mouse and selecting set to items, it leaves the selection mark on the list view.

Comment: I understood wrong. But seems not only me. Maybe you should reformulate the question. Anyways. check those methods calls, im sure are wrong

Comment: I tried but it doest work. E.g. When we select a group of folders we drag our mouse, which intern gives us rectangular box which covers all the items which come under it. That particular rectangle box stays der always. How can I clear it?

Comment: You know #ifdef QT_NO_DEBUG means release mode, right? debug would be:  #ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG. If youre putting code inside and compiling with debug it is not being compiled ...

Comment: I did mention I am running it on release mode :)

Comment: And it compiles `QListView::repaint();` ?

Comment: @Trompa He can call `QListView::repaint()` as his class is a subclass of `QListView`.

Comment: @Trompa: Even if I call repaint() nothing happens. Yes code compiles

Answer (score 0):

Use the [QAbstractItemView::clearSelection](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) function.

If you have subclassed `QListView` you can just call it with `clearSelection();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Clear selection will not let me select the items. My concern is when I am dragging the mouse and selecting set to items, it leaves the selection mark on the list view.

Comment: @Gojira Oh sorry, i misunderstood the question. I thought you had problems clearing the selection.

Comment: @Gojira By the way, what do you mean with "selection mark"? Is it the highlighted selected items, or the dotted-border of the focused item? I'm also confused with your `startDrag` function call. [It takes a drop action as an argument](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#startDrag), yet you're giving it a position? Or is this your own function?

Comment: Its my own function. When we select a group of folders we drag our mouse, which intern gives us rectangular box which covers all the items which come under it. That particular rectangle box stays der always.

Comment: @Gojira How do you create this rectangular box?

Comment: Thats what I explained above. Suppose you have 5 folders.... You press the mouse button and select all the 5 items by dragging the mouse over them. It gives that rectangular look which shows that we have selected the folders. That rectangle doesn't seem to go. Its visible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32470/discussion-between-gojira-and-thuga)